# how to convert 2.0 to four precision floating point number in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
float f = 0.02;
```

The results are equivalent to:

```
f = 0.0200
```

How to do this in C#?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate? Please describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish, and why.

Comment: I suppose he needs the precision for floating points to be 4 in all cases. For the above case, he needs to pad the additional 0s to make it 4.

Answer (score 3):

A floating point number has a *value* (for example 0.02).

When you print it, you can format it into any number of different representations, including "0.002", "0.00200" and "scientific notation".  It's the *same* value with the *same* precision - it's just printed differently (perhaps with a different number of digits after the decimal).

I believe your question is about "formatting":

`String s = String.Format("{0:0.0000}", 0.002);`

Here is much more detail:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format

Comment: +1. I was going to add pretty much the same code to my answer, but that seems redundant since you beat me to it. :-)

Comment: or he can just do: f.ToString("0.0000"); :) same same, +1 anyway

Comment: You can also use the standard format sting `"F4"` instead of `"0.0000"` to obtain fixed-point formatting with four decimals.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, the number is still the same whether the trailing zeros are shown. You can't change what the number ***is***, but you can change how it ***displays*** by using a .ToString() overide.

Specifically the [Zero custom specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0).